# Return all fields in an instance of a derived class

Tags: c#, object, field

I'm looking for a way to return the value of every field in an object in the preferably in the form of a list, but any collection type will work. After a bit of researching, I found this code

```
FieldInfo[] fields = this.GetType().GetFields();

foreach(FieldInfo field in fields)
    // Perform actions
```

Would this be the correct way to handle this? Also, if I put this method in the base class, if a derived class calls it will it return all the fields in the derived class or the base class? (Or more simply put would I need to override this for each derived class?)

It's not a problem to do it individually for each class if that's the only way, but I'm just looking to save a bit of code, since I'm going to have some 50+ derived classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using `GetType()`, so that will return the fields of the *actual* object type, not the type you're declaring the method in. You don't need to override

However, your code will currently only get *public* fields - and I hope you don't have any :)

You probably want something like:

```
var fields = GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance |
                                 BindingFlags.NonPublic |
                                 BindingFlags.Public);
...
```

I *believe* that will include inherited fields (as it's not specifying `BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly`) but you should check.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is a correct way of handling this.

`this.GetType()` whill return the actual type of the object, so if it is a derived class it will return the type of the derived class and it will work as expected. So: No you do not have to override it in each child class.

One thing: `GetType()` returns only the public fields. If you also want other fields then you need to use the overload `GetType(BindingFlags)` and specify the appropriate flags.

Comment: Went ahead and upvoted this as well, thanks for the quick answer!